How can I have make a conditional form using zod react hook form?
so I'm trying to create a form wherein the user have a radio button, if the user press None / No the form will be successfully submitted, but when the user tried to click Yes a new input field needed to be answer.
The problem I'm encountering right now is I still need to answer the optional field.
In the first image, I click next, but nothing shows up.
In the second image,
It works.
How can I make tahe radio button dynamic, but at the same time, make the additonal field required when they choose Yes option?
zodForm.ts
export const formSchemaData = z.object({
    doesHaveDryRun: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "Please indicate if you need a dry-run or not"
    }),
    dryRunDate: z.string().min(1, {
      message: "Please enter the dry run date"
    }),
    dryRunStart: z.string().min(1, {
      message: "Please enter the dry run start time"
    }),
    dryRunEnd: z.string().min(1, {
      message: "Please enter the dry run end time"
    })
  }).refine(data => data.doesHaveDryRun === "yes" ? 
      data.dryRunDate && data.dryRunStart && data.dryRunEnd : true, {
        message: "Dry run fields are required if 'yes' is selected"
  });

Form.ts
https://pastebin.com/HNRF6kRS
Image
Image
Pastebin
